# Android Async Operation Implementation

Tags: java, android, asynchronous

I just started playing around with android and java (c# dev). I wrote a bit of code for loading data in the background, to me it feels right but I wanted to get the input of a few experts.

So here it goes:

I have a basic model:

```
public class Site {
 private String name;

 public String getName(){return name;}
 public void setName(String value){name=value;}
}
```

Async Listener:

```
public interface IAsyncListener<T> {
    public void onTaskDone(T data);
}
```

Data Access Module:

```
public ArrayList<Site> getAllSites() {

    ArrayList<Site> sites = new ArrayList<Site>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Site newSite = new Site();
        newSite.setName("Site" + 1);
        sites.add(newSite);
    }
    return sites;
}

public void getAllSitesAsync(final IAsyncListener<ArrayList<Site>> listener){
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Site>>() {
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<Site> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<Site> sites = getAllSites();

            return sites;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Site> result) {
            listener.onTaskDone(result);
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Finally I consume the data in my activity:

```
private void fetchSites() {
    AppEngine.getInstance().getData().getAllSitesAsync(new IAsyncListener<ArrayList<Site>>() {
        @Override
        public void onTaskDone(ArrayList<Site> data) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            sitesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.sitesListView);
            sites = data;
            sitesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.adapter_item_site, sites);
            sitesListView.setAdapter(sitesArrayAdapter);
            sitesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int i, long l) {
                    loadSite(sites, i);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

All input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the general idea is fine except some non-android issues (ugly code, but I guess it's just a proof of concept).

Things to note:

- There is a dedicated StackExchange site for this kind of questions: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) :)
- Looks like your `getAllSites()` will eventually use either network or database fetching. Be aware that invoking `.execute()` on `AsyncTask` will run it somewhere in the future on single thread background executor. If you intend to cache the result of first query, this may be fine, providing a not-to-large data set. In other case, you may eventually run into this single core executor getting clogged by other `AsyncTask`'s. This kind of work should usually use `.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)` - an multi thread executor, usually configured to number of threads suitable for given device.
- You don't need to recreate your `ListView`'s `Adapter` every time you get new data. You can extend it (usually you will want to extend `BaseAdapter`) with your custom class with `set*` method, inside which you will call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to notify the list about changes. The `set*` method should be called on application main thread, so you should use `runOnUiThread(Runnable)` method of your `Activity`. OR you can always use some of the basic, provided adapters, which also allow to change data.
- `getInstance()` is usually wrong in any kind of language. If you plan to stay with Android for longer, take a look at [Dagger](http://google.github.io/dagger/) library. It may be a little harsh for Java beginners, but you'll see the advantages pretty soon. Android code must be taken with some *special* care, as it likes to get messy.